Postgres not using index when filtered/indexed value does not exist
In Postgres 16.2 I've a table Product with extra index:
CREATE TABLE Product (id   SERIAL , name: text, companyId: number, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE INDEX product_company_id ON Product (companyId);

The table has about 12M rows.
When I search for a row with companyId that exists in the table/index the right "product_company_id" index is used and execution is about 100ms.
select id, name, companyId from Product where companyId=12 order by id limit 1;

But when I search for a row with non existent companyId the execution is very slow about 7s. According to Explain/Analyze the index on companyId is not used:
Limit  (cost=0.09..208.24 rows=1 width=43) (actual time=6404.660..6404.661 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using "Product_pkey" on "Product"  (cost=0.09..562625.56 rows=2703 width=43) (actual time=6404.659..6404.659 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (companyid = 667)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 11797182
Planning Time: 0.100 ms
Execution Time: 6404.674 ms

Removing the "limit" fixes the problem and index is used again. But the limit is important.
Is there any way to force the DB to use the index to find out there are no matching rows?

Yes, you can have a two-dimensional index of the form of:
CREATE INDEX product_company_id ON Product ((companyId / 1000000),companyId);

that is, the first dimension of the index is generating clusters of slots for 1000000-partitions and if therefore you filter by companyId being 12, it is having a 0 in the first index and looks for the million of companies in that range rather than the entirety of the table. You can of course change the 1000000 to some other number.
Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ueAq14fNuYbq7Wy9TJXxFL/0
Running
explain select * from Product where CompanyId = 12

yields:
QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on product (cost=13.15..22.62 rows=6 width=40)
Recheck Cond: (companyid = 12)
-> Bitmap Index Scan on product_company_id (cost=0.00..13.15 rows=6 width=0)
Index Cond: (companyid = 12)


Have you tried running this with limit in place?

What possible utility could this recommendation have?  That an index is chosen to be used on an empty, unanalyzed, table with a different query than the one at question is not of any use to anyone.

@jjanes : question stated, that adding a limit leads to the plan not using the index.

@clamp Removing the limit shouldn't also remove the order by.

@jjanes Yes and this answer uses neither limit nor order by.

@clamp Yes, which is why it is not relevant to the question.  Lajos' answer looks like AI generated garbage, although possible it is some other kind of garbage.

@jjanes it was written by hand.

PostgreSQL cannot know with certainty that no rows will match that given companyId. In fact it thinks that 2703 will.  You could try to improve that estimate by making sure ANALYZE has been run on the table, or by increasing the stats target for that column and then running ANALYZE.
Or, you could just create a more robust index, for example one on (companyId, id).  This index will still look attractive and so probably be used even if the row estimate is wrong.
